# Why does IMAP authentication fail on my outlook hosted email?

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, imap

I am using IMAP to access an Outlook inbox.

I am authenticating as so, taking the IMAP info from the account:

```
    var imap = new Imap({
        user: user.name,
        password: user.pass,
        host: 'outlook.office365.com',
        port: 993,
        tls: true
      });
```

This returns the following error

```
Error: LOGIN failed.
    at Connection._resTagged (/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1502:11)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:194:10)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Parser._resTagged (/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:175:10)
    at Parser._parse (/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:139:16)
    at Parser._tryread (/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:82:15)
    at TLSSocket.Parser._cbReadable (/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:53:12)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:578:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'no',
  textCode: undefined,
  source: 'authentication'
}
```

I can't find any info on this error, can you see what I'm missing?

Comment: "LOGIN failed" usually means that the user name and/or password is incorrect.

Comment: LOGIN is going to fail on Outlook hosted email even with the right password, because they disabled all mechanisms that transmit passwords across the net.

Comment: They have been telegraphing for nearly two years that you cannot log in with a password: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

Comment: Thanks Max & arnt, that will explain it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Outlook has recently stopped supporting Basic Auth through IMAP
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/cannot-connect-mailbox-pop-imap-outlook

This seems to be the cause for the error. For anyone looking to get access to mail on an outlook server I'd recommend looking into creating an Azure app and  using Microsoft's GraphQL API. That's worked for me.